# Google Line Chart saying Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getSelection' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I'm using Google Chart (Line chart in particular). The chart is displayed correctly. Now I'm trying to add  interaction, when the label of the series is clicked then the series should disappear and and appear.

My problem is that the method getSelection() is throwing the error

```
Cannot call method 'getSelection' of null
```

This is part of my code:

```
var jsonData = $.ajax({
url: 'http://localhost:9580/LocalApp/api/Data?Number=16846851',
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'json',
success: function (values) {

// now we need to build the map data, loop over each result

// create columns array
var columns = [{ id: 'datetime', label: 'Date and Time', type: 'datetime' },
           { id: 'x', label: 'X', type: 'number' },
           { id: 'y', label: 'Y', type: 'number' },
           { id: 'z', label: 'Z', type: 'number' },
           { id: 'total', label: 'Total', type: 'number' }];

var chartData = new google.visualization.DataTable(
{
    cols: columns
});

// Add empty rows
chartData.addRows(values.ac.length);

$.each(values.ac, function (indexInArray, ac) {
    chartData.setCell(indexInArray, 0, new Date(acc.dateTime));
    chartData.setCell(indexInArray, 1, ac.x);
    chartData.setCell(indexInArray, 2, ac.y);
    chartData.setCell(indexInArray, 3, ac.z);
    chartData.setCell(indexInArray, 4, ac.total);
});

var options = {
    title: 'Data',
    pointSize:4, 
    legend: { position: 'bottom' },
    series: {
        0: { color: 'blue',   lineWidth: 2 },
        1: { color: 'red',    lineWidth: 2 },
        2: { color: 'green',  lineWidth: 2 },
        3: { color: 'yellow', lineWidth: 2 }
    }
};

function showHideSeries(newChart) {
    var sel = newChart.getSelection(); **--> error**
    // if selection length is 0, we deselected an element
    if (sel.length > 0) {
        // if row is undefined, we clicked on the legend
        if (sel[0].row == null) {
            var col = sel[0].column;
            if (columns[col] == col) {
                // hide the data series
                columns[col] = {
                    label: data.getColumnLabel(col),
                    type: data.getColumnType(col),
                    calc: function () {
                        return null;
                    }
                };
                // grey out the legend entry
                series[col - 1].color = '#CCCCCC';
            }
            else {
                // show the data series
                columns[col] = col;
                series[col - 1].color = null;
            }
            var view = new google.visualization.DataView(chartData);
            view.setColumns(columns);
            newChart.draw(view, options);
        }
    }
}

// Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', showHideSeries(chart));
chart.draw(chartData, options);
```

Any idea why I'm getting that error?
Thanks!!! Guillermo.

Comment: `google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', showHideSeries(chart));` line looks incorrect. `(chart)` shouldn't be there because `showHideSeries` doesn't return a function for the event to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', showHideSeries(chart));
```

is calling the `showHideSeries` function and passing its return value (`null`) to the `addListener` function.  You need to pass a function (not a function call!  [unless that function also returns a function]) to `addListener`.  This would be valid:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', showHideSeries);
```

and would give you the error you posted in your question, as the event listener passes an event object as the parameter to the listener, not a chart object, and the event object definitely does not have a `getSelection` method.  Given your code as-is, I don't think you would get the error you posted, but it still wouldn't work anyway.

There are two different ways you could fix this: either use `chart` instead of `newChart` inside `showHideSeries` (which works as long as `showHideSeries` will only be used by one chart) or you can wrap the `showHideSeries(chart);` call inside another function.  Going the first route should be self-evident, so I will focus on the second here in case you need to use this function with multiple charts:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function() {
    showHideSeries(chart);
});
```

When the "select" event fires, the anonymous function is called, which then calls `showHideSeries` with the chart variable.  If you had another chart you needed to use this with, it would be as simple as this:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(otherChart, 'select', function() {
    showHideSeries(otherChart);
});
```

Comment: You didn't only answered my question but explained the answer as well, in that way we can learn. Thank you very much!!